# accessing the "Copy Local" property of a MetadataReference in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

quick question: how do you get access to the "Copy Local" property of a `MetadataReference` in Roslyn?

This property is used to determine if a reference should be copied in the output directory upon compilation or not (for example system libs typically do not get copied).

When accessing the the `Properties` field of a `MetadataReference` (as follows), there is no such option:

```
var reference = compilation.ExternalReferences[0];
reference.Properties.
```

But I can see other options such as `Aliases`, `EmbedInteropTypes` and `Kind`. I tried to cast it to another Reference type, but still cannot see further options (as you can see them in Visual Studio). Am I missing something?

Comment: That's an MSBuild property; it doesn't actually have anything to do with the compiler.

Comment: @SLaks We would like to do the same thing.  If this is an MSBuild property can we obtain it via MSBuildWorkspace, which we are already using to open the solution and iterate through projects.  We can't seem to find anything along the lines of "CopyLocal" anywhere.

Comment: You need to use the MSBuild API.  Roslyn reads references at http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/CSharp/CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.cs,66